# How to import data as each tick's parameter in NetLogo?

Tags: import, netlogo

I have a text data set of each day's stock price and buying signals (1 is buy, -1 is sell and 0 is doing nothing). How can I import the data into NetLogo so tick 1 will be day 1 with all the information in first line, and for each tick I can have different prices and signals based on the data?

The data I have is in this format:

tick price signal1 signal2 signal3

1   5.795   0   0   0

2   5.805   0   0   0

3   5.815   0   0   0

4   5.8 0   0   0

5   5.8 0   0   0

6   5.81    0   0   0

7   5.845   0   0   0

8   5.855   0   0   0

9   5.85    0   0   0

10  5.87    0   0   0

11  5.885   0   0   0

12  5.865   0   0   0

13  5.855   0   0   0

14  5.835   0   0   0

15  5.84    -1  0   1

```
globals [
  global-counter
  global-price
  global-signal1
  global-signal2
  global-signal3
]

turtles-own [
  cash
  stock
  total-asset
  w1
  w2
  w3
  w
]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  create-turtle
  stock-import
end

to create-turtle
  create-turtles 100
  ask turtles [ 
    set shape "person"
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set cash 1000
    set stock 0
    set w1 random-float 1
    set w2 random-float ( 1 - w1 )
    set w3 1 - w1 - w2
  ]
end

to stock-import
  file-open "data.txt"
  while [ not file-at-end? ]
  [ 
    set global-counter [ ]
    set global-price [ ]
    set global-signal1 [ ]
    set global-signal2 [ ]
    set global-signal3 [ ]


    let counter file-read
    let price file-read
    let signal1 file-read
    let signal2 file-read
    let signal3 file-read

    set global-counter lput counter global-counter
    set global-price lput price global-price
    set global-signal1 lput signal1 global-signal1
    set global-signal2 lput signal2 global-signal2
    set global-signal3 lput signal3 global-signal3
  ]
  file-close
end

to make-one-trade
  ask turtles [ set w ( w1 * global-signal1 + w2 * global-signal2 + w3 * global-signal3 )
    set cash ( cash - w * global-price )
    set stock ( stock + w1 + w2 + w3 )
    set total-asset ( cash + stock * global-price )
  ]
end

to go
  make-one-trade
  tick
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data file really uses a single space to delimit data, then you can use the `csv` module and specify a delimiter:

```
extensions [csv]
to setup
  ca
end

to go
  file-open "c:/temp/temp.csv"
  if file-at-end? [ stop ]  ;; protect against end of file
  ;;read a single line (specifying delimiter)
  let _line (csv:from-row file-read-line " ")
  print _line  ;;or do what you want
end
```

OT: why is your data space delimited?  The csv format (i.e., **comma** separated values) is an established international data-exchange standard:
http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000323.shtml

Comment: Thanks Alan. I'll try what you told me after this shift. The data is space delimited because it was in an Excel file and I simply Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V to a blank txt file.

Comment: @lovedavidsilva You are probably aware, but just in case: Excel supports export to the CSV format.